# Route: product.details URI: product/{slug} Missing parameter: slug] error in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

Missing required parameter for [Route: product.details] [URI: product/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\livewire\items-component.blade.php).This is the error message I receive.

Inside the web.php I have this :
 `Route::get('/product/{slug}', DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');`

In the DetailsComponent.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;
class DetailsComponent extends Component
{

    public $slug;
    public function mount($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug',$this->slug)->first();
        return view('livewire.details-component',['product'=>$product])->layout('layouts.details');
    }
}
```

Inside the items-component.blade.php:

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)
        <!-- grid item #1 -->
 <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}">
        <div id="TEST" class="activities" style=" background-image: url({{asset('images')}}/{{$product->image}}"  >
           
          <h1 class="activities-h1">
    EUW
          </h1>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0">
         <div class="card-body">

              <h6 class="iconss">
                  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  <i class="far fa-star"></i>
              </h6>

          </div>

         </div>

                       <div class="card-stuff">

                    <p class="card-text">{{$product->name}}</p>
                    <span class="price">{{$product->regular_price}}</span>
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
</a>
        @endforeach
```

In the details-component.blade.php:
      `<h2 class="price-h2">{{$product->name}}</h2>`

Any idea how to solve this error??

Comment: Look in `all-component.blade.php`, the error seems to be coming from there

Comment: @aynber my bad its from items-component.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using livewire component, you should use the @livewire directive instead of route(), According to your component name I think you must use this:

```
@livewire('details-component', ['slug' => $product->slug])
```

Instead of this:

```
{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specif specify method name in route .

```
 Route::get('/product/{slug}', [DetailsComponent::class,'MethodName'])->name('product.details');
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are passing parameter name or arguments in route in web.php you dont need to send the name of passing argument because you have already passed it.

you should write this way-

Route should be in Web. php

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}',DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');


{{route('product.details',$product->slug)}}
```

if you using normal route with passing any argument in web.php then you use it that way

route should be like this way

```
Route::get('/product',DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');


{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @foreach($brands as $brand)
        <div class="col position-relative">
            <div class="text-bg-secondary p-sm-1 h-100">
                <a href="{{ route('brands.show', $brand->slug) }}" class="small link-light stretched-link text-decoration-none">
                    {{ $brand->name }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).